# Rails: test update action put request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, request, action, put

I'm trying to test manually updating a user through update action.

I've tried the following line of code in spec/requests/user_request_spec.rb:

```
user = create(:user, username: "username", password: "secret", password_confirmation: "secret") #Factory Girl
attr = { username: "newusername" }
put :update, :id => user.id, :user => attr
```

And I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: put :update, :id => user.id, :user => attr
ArgumentError:
  bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)
# ./spec/requests/users_request_spec.rb:55:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How can I send a request to update a user through rspec?

Comment: Does this example help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223336/how-to-write-an-rspec-test-for-a-simple-put-update

Comment: Updated the question to mirror the example and no same problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where 'put' is being defined, I would have expected a no method error. You must be including something else that defines put.

In any case, include `Rack::Test::Methods` in your test, it should provide what you're after:

```
describe Foo do
  include Rack::Test::Methods # provides get, post, put, etc

  ...
end
```