# Controller spec .reload error: no implicit conversion of nil into Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My rspec tests are failing when I try to use .reload to test the Update method.

**The error**

```
Admin::CompaniesController PUT update valid attributes changes @company's attributes
 Failure/Error: @company.reload
 TypeError:
   no implicit conversion of nil into Hash
 # ./spec/controllers/admin/admin_companies_controller_spec.rb:81:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**The spec**

```
# spec/controllers/admin_companies_controller_spec.rb
describe 'PUT update' do
  before :each do
    @company = create(:company, name: "Rockstars", phone: "3035551212")
  end

  context "valid attributes" do
    it "changes @company's attributes" do
      put :update, id: @company, company: attributes_for(:company, name: "Fishstars")
      @company.reload       #line 81
      expect( @company.name ).to eq("Fishstars")
    end
  end
end
```

I have **also tried (1)** using let!(),  (same error)

```
describe 'PUT update' do

  let!(:company)  { create(:company, name: "Rockstars", phone: "303555121d") }

  context "valid attributes" do
    it "changes company's attributes" do
      put :update, id: company, company: attributes_for(:company, name: "Fishstars")
      company.reload       #line 81
      expect( company.name ).to eq("Fishstars")
    end
  end
end
```

I have **also tried (2)** (same error)

```
  before :each do
    @company = create(:company, name: "Rockstars", phone: "3035551212")
  end

  it "changes @company's attributes" do
    @attr = { name: "Fishstars" }
    put :update, id: @company.id, :company => @attr
    @company.reload
    expect( @company.name ).to eq("Fishstars")
  end
```

My first thought was that the variable @company was nil, but if I comment out line 81 (indicated) the test fails as expected.

**Update**

inserting 'byebug' just before line 81 allows me to see what @company looks like:

```
(byebug) @company
#<Company id: 1, name: "Rockstars", hq_address: "MyString", hq_city: "MyString", hq_state: "MyString", country: "MyString", description: "Description 1", phone: "3035551212", email: "Example2email@gmail.com", owner_id: 2, contact_name: "MyString", created_at: "2014-07-11 19:02:24", updated_at: "2014-07-11 19:02:24", active: true, logo_file_name: nil, logo_content_type: nil, logo_file_size: nil, logo_updated_at: nil, slug: "rockstars", refund_policy: "Refund policy">

(byebug) @company.reload
TypeError Exception: no implicit conversion of nil into Hash
nil
```

Comment: Have you tried doing exactly as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223336/how-to-write-an-rspec-test-for-a-simple-put-update

Comment: I have, and I received exactly the same error. Question updated with that attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out why .reload wasn't working, but I replaced it with a find_by_id call and my tests are working properly now:

```
# new code - effectively tests the update method
@company = Company.find_by_id(@company)

# original code - causes errors
@company.reload       #line 81
```